# GL opens in TTY terminal, but not if X is present

Tags: terminal, x11, tty, opengl

asdfdsgAlthough it may seem incredible, I have the problem that **GL** does not open if X is open, but if X is not open it does open.

And I know this because I tested it with the video game **Warzone 2100**, when I log out and there is only a TTY terminal, it does detect GL and open the game, and I can play as normal.

I'm getting this error along with a message in Arabic, which basically says the same thing as the error but in that language:

```bash
warzone2100 
fatal   |09:34:57: [wzMainScreenSetup_CreateVideoWindow:2927] Can't create a window, because: GLX is not supported
```

[image: warzone2100 error creating window]

The problem is specifically that when X is on it does not detect GL. Apparently it's not a bug in the video game, because glxgears doesn't work for me either.

Error **glxgears**:

```bash
glxgears
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

**ldd glxgears**

```js
/usr/bin/glxgears
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc681d6000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fae6c09d000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fae6bf5a000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fae6be6d000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fae6bc8b000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007fae6bbd3000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007fae6bb9f000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fae6bb74000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib/ld-2.38.so (0x00007fae6c12d000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fae6bb6f000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fae6bb67000)
```

**realpath libGL**

```bash
realpath /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1.7.0
```

**Video info**

```js
  Video-Info 1.5.1 - sáb 23 dic 2023 on LxPupSc64 20.06 - Linux 5.7.2-lxpup64 x86_64
   
  Chip description:
    0.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)  
   
  X Server: Xorg  Driver used: nouveau
  X.Org version: 21.1.10
    dimensions:    1280x1024 pixels (312x234 millimeters)
    depth of root window:    24 planes
```

**uname -a**

```bash
uname -a
Linux puppypc19012 5.7.2-lxpup64 #1 SMP Sat Jun 13 11:12:52 BST 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**inxi**

```js
inxi 
CPU~Dual core Pentium E5700 (-MCP-) speed/max~2764/2969 MHz Kernel~5.7.2-lxpup64 x86_64 Up~1:47 Mem~1039.6/1990.8MB HDD~80.0GB(84.8% used) Procs~176 Client~Shell inxi~2.3.8
```

**/proc/cpuinfo**

```js
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5700  @ 3.00GHz
stepping    : 10
microcode   : 0xa07
cpu MHz     : 2931.525
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm xsave lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority vpid dtherm
vmx flags   : vnmi flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr vapic
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 6037.59
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5700  @ 3.00GHz
stepping    : 10
microcode   : 0xa07
cpu MHz     : 2912.258
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm xsave lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority vpid dtherm
vmx flags   : vnmi flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr vapic
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 6037.59
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

```bash
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "IgnoreABI" "true"
    Option "DontVTSwitch" "true"
    Option "RandR" "on"
    Option "AutoAddDevices" "true"
    Option "DontZap" "false"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    #InputDevice "Synaptics Mouse" "AlwaysCore" #serverlayoutsynaptics
    # InputDevice "VboxMouse" "CorePointer" 
    #InputDevice "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    #InputDevice "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/X11/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/local"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/TTF"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/OTF"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/truetype"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/opentype"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/woff"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/CID"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/X11/fonts/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/OTF"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/X11/fonts"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/share/fonts"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/share/X11/fonts"
EndSection

Section "Module"
Load "synaptics" #loadsynaptics
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
    HorizSync    35-81
    VertRefresh  59-76
    #UseModes     "Modes0" #monitor0usemodes
#   Option      "PreferredMode" "1024x768" #monitor0prefmode
EndSection

Section "Modes"
    Identifier "Modes0"
    #modes0modeline0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "nouveau" #card0driver
    BusID       "1:0:0" #card0busid
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
#   Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
#   DefaultDepth 24
    #Option         "metamodes" "1280x800_60 +0+0" #METAMODES_0
    Subsection "Display"
        Depth       24 #screen0depth
        Modes       "1280x1024" #screen0modes
    EndSubsection
EndSection
```

**ls -Rlh /usr/lib/X11/modules**

```js
/usr/lib/X11/modules:
total 730K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  105 dic 17 14:20 dri
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 1,3K dic 16 10:43 drivers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   32 dic 16 01:28 extensions
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  474 dic 16 11:00 input
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 103K dic 16 01:28 libexa.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23K dic 16 01:28 libfbdevhw.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 217K dic 16 01:28 libglamoregl.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 164K dic 16 01:28 libint10.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15K dic 16 01:28 libshadowfb.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39K dic 16 01:28 libshadow.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  36K dic 16 01:28 libvgahw.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 136K dic 16 01:28 libwfb.so

/usr/lib/X11/modules/dri:
total 30M
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 dic 17 14:20 kms_swrast_dri.so -> libgallium_dri.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30M sep 25 17:28 libgallium_dri.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 dic 17 14:20 swrast_dri.so -> libgallium_dri.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 dic 17 14:20 zink_dri.so -> libgallium_dri.so

/usr/lib/X11/modules/drivers:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 amdgpu_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 amdgpu_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 dic 16 10:43 apm_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/apm_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 dic 16 10:43 ark_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/ark_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 dic 16 10:43 ast_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/ast_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 dic 16 10:43 ati_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 dic 16 10:43 ati_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 dic 16 10:43 chips_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/chips_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 dic 16 10:43 cirrus_alpine.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/cirrus_alpine.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 cirrus_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/cirrus_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 dic 16 10:43 cirrus_laguna.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/cirrus_laguna.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 dic 16 10:43 dummy_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/dummy_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 dic 16 10:43 dummy_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/dummy_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 dic 16 10:43 fbdev_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 dic 16 10:43 fbdev_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 dic 16 10:43 geode_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/geode_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 dic 16 10:43 glint_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/glint_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 dic 16 10:43 i128_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/i128_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 dic 16 10:43 i740_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/i740_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 dic 16 10:43 intel_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 dic 16 10:43 intel_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 mach64_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/mach64_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 dic 16 10:43 mga_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/mga_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 dic 16 10:43 modesetting_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 dic 16 10:43 modesetting_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 dic 16 10:43 neomagic_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/neomagic_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 dic 16 10:43 nouveau_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 dic 16 10:43 nouveau_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 dic 16 10:43 nv_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/nv_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 dic 16 10:43 openchrome_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/openchrome_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 dic 16 10:43 openchrome_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/openchrome_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 dic 16 10:43 qxl_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/qxl_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 dic 16 10:43 r128_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/r128_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 radeon_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 radeon_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 dic 16 10:43 rdp -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/rdp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 dic 16 10:43 rendition_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/rendition_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 dic 16 10:43 s3_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/s3_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 dic 16 10:43 s3virge_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/s3virge_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 savage_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/savage_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 dic 16 10:43 siliconmotion_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/siliconmotion_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 dic 16 10:43 sis_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/sis_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 sisusb_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/sisusb_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 sisusb_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/sisusb_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 dic 16 10:43 spiceqxl_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/spiceqxl_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 dic 16 10:43 tdfx_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/tdfx_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 dic 16 10:43 tga_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/tga_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 dic 16 10:43 trident_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/trident_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 dic 16 10:43 tseng_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/tseng_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 dic 16 10:43 v4l_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/v4l_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 dic 16 10:43 vboxvideo_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/vboxvideo_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 dic 16 10:43 vesa_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 dic 16 10:43 vesa_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 vmware_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 vmware_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 voodoo_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/voodoo_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 voodoo_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/voodoo_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 dic 16 10:43 xrdpdev_drv.a -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/xrdpdev_drv.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 dic 16 10:43 xrdpdev_drv.so -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/xrdpdev_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 dic 16 10:43 ztv_drv.la -> ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/ztv_drv.la

/usr/lib/X11/modules/extensions:
total 292K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 292K dic 16 01:28 libglx.so

/usr/lib/X11/modules/input:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 dic 16 11:00 acecad_drv.la -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/acecad_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 dic 16 11:00 elographics_drv.so -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/elographics_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 dic 16 11:00 evdev_drv.so -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 dic 16 11:00 inputtest_drv.so -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/inputtest_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 dic 16 11:00 joystick_drv.la -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/joystick_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 dic 16 11:00 kbd_drv.la -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/kbd_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 dic 16 11:00 libinput_drv.la -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 dic 16 11:00 libinput_drv.so -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 dic 16 11:00 mouse_drv.la -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/mouse_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 dic 16 11:00 penmount_drv.la -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/penmount_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 dic 16 11:00 synaptics_drv.so -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 dic 16 11:00 vmmouse_drv.la -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/vmmouse_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 dic 16 11:00 vmmouse_drv.so -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/vmmouse_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 dic 16 11:00 void_drv.la -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/void_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 dic 16 11:00 void_drv.so -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/void_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 dic 16 11:00 wacom_drv.la -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 dic 16 11:00 wacom_drv.so -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 dic 16 11:00 xrdpkeyb_drv.a -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/xrdpkeyb_drv.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 dic 16 11:00 xrdpkeyb_drv.so -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/xrdpkeyb_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 dic 16 11:00 xrdpmouse_drv.a -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/xrdpmouse_drv.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 dic 16 11:00 xrdpmouse_drv.so -> ../../../../lib/xorg/modules/input/xrdpmouse_drv.so
```

**ls -Rlh /usr/lib/xorg**

```js
/usr/lib/xorg:
total 30K
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4,0K dic 23 10:53 modules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26K dic 13 00:13 protocol.txt

/usr/lib/xorg/modules:
total 1,1M
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 1,3K dic 16 09:35 drivers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   49 dic 16 00:44 extensions
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K dic 23 10:54 input
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  923 may  1  2020 libexa.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  99K dic 13 00:13 libexa.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  936 may  1  2020 libfbdevhw.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  23K dic 13 00:13 libfbdevhw.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  917 may  1  2020 libfb.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  961 may  1  2020 libglamoregl.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 225K dic 13 00:13 libglamoregl.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  935 may  1  2020 libint10.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 164K dic 13 00:13 libint10.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  953 may  1  2020 libshadowfb.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  15K dic 13 00:13 libshadowfb.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  930 may  1  2020 libshadow.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  39K dic 13 00:13 libshadow.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  912 may  1  2020 libvbe.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  935 may  1  2020 libvgahw.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  40K dic 13 00:13 libvgahw.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  923 may  1  2020 libwfb.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 140K dic 13 00:13 libwfb.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 214K dic 16 09:37 libxorgxrdp.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 103K dic 16 09:37 libxorgxrdp.so

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers:
total 3,7M
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  965 oct 11  2019 amdgpu_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 158K feb 22  2023 amdgpu_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  930 feb 10  2019 apm_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  914 may 11  2018 ark_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  914 may 11  2018 ast_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  933 oct 15  2019 ati_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  15K abr 25  2023 ati_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  942 feb 16  2019 chips_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  968 may 11  2018 cirrus_alpine.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  950 may 11  2018 cirrus_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  968 may 11  2018 cirrus_laguna.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  940 may 11  2018 dummy_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  23K may 11  2023 dummy_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  925 jun  1  2018 fbdev_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  27K nov  7  2021 fbdev_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  941 sep 21  2019 geode_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  925 may 11  2018 glint_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  936 dic 12  2018 i128_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  936 dic  7  2018 i740_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  986 ene 19  2020 intel_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1,7M feb  2  2023 intel_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  931 may 19  2018 mach64_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  930 dic 12  2018 mga_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  981 may  1  2020 modesetting_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 117K dic 13 00:13 modesetting_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  960 dic 27  2018 neomagic_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  964 ene 29  2019 nouveau_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 221K dic 16 11:28 nouveau_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  907 may 11  2018 nv_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  985 may 11  2018 openchrome_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 244K abr  1  2023 openchrome_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 165K may 16  2023 qxl_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  936 oct 23  2018 r128_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  965 oct 15  2019 radeon_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 483K abr 25  2023 radeon_drv.so
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  130 dic 16 09:35 rdp
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  949 may 19  2018 rendition_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  924 jul 26  2019 s3_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  954 feb 10  2019 s3virge_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  931 mar 17  2019 savage_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  973 may 11  2018 siliconmotion_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  928 dic  3  2019 sis_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  931 may 11  2018 sisusb_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  84K nov  7  2021 sisusb_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 190K may 16  2023 spiceqxl_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  936 feb 16  2019 tdfx_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  914 may 11  2018 tga_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  941 may 11  2018 trident_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  926 jul 14  2018 tseng_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  913 ago 17  2018 v4l_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  964 may 11  2018 vboxvideo_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  919 may 11  2018 vesa_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  32K dic 10  2022 vesa_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  956 sep 30  2019 vmware_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 175K ene 24  2023 vmware_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  932 may 11  2018 voodoo_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  27K dic 10  2022 voodoo_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23K dic 16 09:37 xrdpdev_drv.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  23K dic 16 09:37 xrdpdev_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  929 sep 21  2019 ztv_drv.la

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp:
total 99K
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  64 dic 16 09:35 rdp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 99K feb 21  2023 xorgxrdp-0.9.19-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 26 feb 21  2023 etc
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 26 dic 16 09:35 install
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 51 feb 21  2023 usr

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/etc:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 27 feb 21  2023 X11

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/etc/X11:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 32 feb 21  2023 xrdp

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/etc/X11/xrdp:
total 2,0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,7K feb 21  2023 xorg.conf

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/install:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 48 dic 16 09:35 rdp

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/install/rdp:
total 2,5K
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  163 dic 16 09:35 in2.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,7K dic 16 09:35 rbo-rdp.txt

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/usr:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 27 feb 21  2023 lib
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 31 feb 21  2023 share

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/usr/lib:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 30 feb 21  2023 xorg

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/usr/lib/xorg:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 86 feb 21  2023 modules

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/usr/lib/xorg/modules:
total 317K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   58 feb 21  2023 drivers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  107 feb 21  2023 input
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 214K feb 21  2023 libxorgxrdp.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 103K feb 21  2023 libxorgxrdp.so

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers:
total 46K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23K feb 21  2023 xrdpdev_drv.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 23K feb 21  2023 xrdpdev_drv.so

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input:
total 54K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17K feb 21  2023 xrdpkeyb_drv.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14K feb 21  2023 xrdpkeyb_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8,5K feb 21  2023 xrdpmouse_drv.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14K feb 21  2023 xrdpmouse_drv.so

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/usr/share:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 31 feb 21  2023 licenses

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/usr/share/licenses:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 30 feb 21  2023 xorgxrdp

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rdp/rdp/usr/share/licenses/xorgxrdp:
total 1,0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 967 feb 21  2023 COPYING

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions:
total 309K
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  933 may  1  2020 libglx.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 308K dic 13 00:13 libglx.so

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input:
total 498K
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  949 may 11  2018 acecad_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  27K dic  9  2022 elographics_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  67K nov  7  2021 evdev_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  27K dic 13 00:13 inputtest_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  941 may 11  2018 joystick_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  911 may 11  2018 kbd_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  953 may 19  2020 libinput_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  87K ago 25 02:57 libinput_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  923 jun 19  2018 mouse_drv.la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  940 may 11  2018 penmount_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  75K jul 11  2022 synaptics_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  936 may 11  2018 vmmouse_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  23K oct  8  2022 vmmouse_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  918 dic 13  2018 void_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14K nov  7  2022 void_drv.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  936 dic 24  2019 wacom_drv.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 116K abr  6  2023 wacom_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17K dic 16 09:37 xrdpkeyb_drv.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14K dic 16 09:37 xrdpkeyb_drv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8,5K dic 16 09:37 xrdpmouse_drv.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14K dic 16 09:37 xrdpmouse_drv.so
```

**Part of /usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt**

```js
// ...
R000 DRI2:QueryVersion
R001 DRI2:Connect
R002 DRI2:Authenticate
R003 DRI2:CreateDrawable
R004 DRI2:DestroyDrawable
R005 DRI2:GetBuffers
R006 DRI2:CopyRegion
R007 DRI2:GetBuffersWithFormat
R008 DRI2:SwapBuffers
R009 DRI2:GetMSC
R010 DRI2:WaitMSC
R011 DRI2:WaitSBC
R012 DRI2:SwapInterval
V000 DRI2:BufferSwapComplete
V001 DRI2:InvalidateBuffers
R000 DRI3:QueryVersion
R001 DRI3:Open
R002 DRI3:PixmapFromBuffer
R003 DRI3:BufferFromPixmap
R004 DRI3:FenceFromFD
R005 DRI3:FDFromFence
// ...
R001 GLX:
R002 GLX:Large
R003 GLX:CreateContext
R004 GLX:DestroyContext
R005 GLX:MakeCurrent
R006 GLX:IsDirect
R007 GLX:QueryVersion
R008 GLX:WaitGL
R009 GLX:WaitX
R010 GLX:CopyContext
R011 GLX:SwapBuffers
R012 GLX:UseXFont
R013 GLX:CreateGLXPixmap
R014 GLX:GetVisualConfigs
R015 GLX:DestroyGLXPixmap
R016 GLX:VendorPrivate
R017 GLX:VendorPrivateWithReply
R018 GLX:QueryExtensionsString
R019 GLX:QueryServerString
R020 GLX:ClientInfo
R021 GLX:GetFBConfigs
R022 GLX:CreatePixmap
R023 GLX:DestroyPixmap
R024 GLX:CreateNewContext
R025 GLX:QueryContext
R026 GLX:MakeContextCurrent
R027 GLX:CreatePbuffer
R028 GLX:DestroyPbuffer
R029 GLX:GetDrawableAttributes
R030 GLX:ChangeDrawableAttributes
R031 GLX:CreateWindow
R032 GLX:DeleteWindow
R033 GLX:SetClientInfoARB
R034 GLX:CreateContextAttribsARB
R035 GLX:SetClientInfo2ARB
R101 GLX:NewList
R102 GLX:EndList
R103 GLX:DeleteLists
R104 GLX:GenLists
R105 GLX:FeedbackBuffer
R106 GLX:SelectBuffer
R107 GLX:Mode
R108 GLX:Finish
R109 GLX:PixelStoref
R110 GLX:PixelStorei
R111 GLX:ReadPixels
R112 GLX:GetBooleanv
R113 GLX:GetClipPlane
R114 GLX:GetDoublev
R115 GLX:GetError
R116 GLX:GetFloatv
R117 GLX:GetIntegerv
R118 GLX:GetLightfv
R119 GLX:GetLightiv
R120 GLX:GetMapdv
R121 GLX:GetMapfv
R122 GLX:GetMapiv
R123 GLX:GetMaterialfv
R124 GLX:GetMaterialiv
R125 GLX:GetPixelfv
R126 GLX:GetPixelMapuiv
R127 GLX:GetPixelMapusv
R128 GLX:GetPolygonStipple
R129 GLX:GetString
R130 GLX:GetTexEnvfv
R131 GLX:GetTexEnviv
R132 GLX:GetTexGendv
R133 GLX:GetTexGenfv
R134 GLX:GetTexGeniv
R135 GLX:GetTexImage
R136 GLX:GetTexParameterfv
R137 GLX:GetTexParameteriv
R138 GLX:GetTexLevelParameterfv
R139 GLX:GetTexLevelParameteriv
R140 GLX:IsEnabled
R141 GLX:IsList
R142 GLX:Flush
R143 GLX:AreTexturesResident
R144 GLX:DeleteTextures
R145 GLX:GenTextures
R146 GLX:IsTexture
R147 GLX:GetColorTable
R148 GLX:GetColorTableParameterfv
R149 GLX:GetColorTableParameterfv
R150 GLX:GetConvolutionFilter
R151 GLX:GetConvolutionParameterfv
R152 GLX:GetConvolutionParameteriv
R153 GLX:GetSeparableFilter
R154 GLX:GetHistogram
R155 GLX:GetHistogramParameterfv
R156 GLX:GetHistogramParameteriv
R157 GLX:GetMinmax
R158 GLX:GetMinmaxParameterfv
R159 GLX:GetMinmaxParameteriv
R160 GLX:GetCompressedTexImage
V000 GLX:PbufferClobber
V001 GLX:BufferSwapComplete
E000 GLX:BadContext
E001 GLX:BadContextState
E002 GLX:BadDrawable
E003 GLX:BadPixmap
E004 GLX:BadContextTag
E005 GLX:BadCurrentWindow
E006 GLX:BadRenderRequest
E007 GLX:BadLargeRequest
E008 GLX:UnsupportedPrivateRequest
E009 GLX:BadFBConfig
E010 GLX:BadPbuffer
E011 GLX:BadCurrentDrawable
E012 GLX:BadWindow
// ...
```

Comment: Zero info on your system or how you are accessing it. If you want help, then do not drip feed info.

Comment: @Bib Ok, I already added the system information. If more information is needed I will add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you have to look at

```js
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep "(EE)"
```

In this case, what was necessary was to install these three packages:

- **llvm 11**: https://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/linux/altlinux/p10/branch/x86_64/RPMS.classic/llvm11.0-libs-11.0.1-alt6.x86_64.rpm
- **xorg-dri-nouveau**: https://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/linux/altlinux/Sisyphus/x86_64/RPMS.classic/xorg-dri-nouveau-23.3.1-alt1.x86_64.rpm
- **libffi7**: https://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/linux/altlinux/Sisyphus/x86_64/RPMS.classic/libffi7-3.3-alt2.x86_64.rpm

Then make symbolic links:

```js
cd /usr/lib/X11/modules/dri
ln -sv ../../../xorg/modules/drivers/* .
```

Also before installing the packages, you must extract it and move the *lib64* folders to *lib*.